# Next.js and Jest proper configuration for next-page-tester

Tags: jestjs, next.js

I'm writing tests for a NextJS app and I can't get Jest to work properly. Most tests work, but sometimes I get this error when I have to deal with  component:

```
    Failed to parse src "test-file-stub" on `next/image`, if using relative image it must start with a leading slash "/" or be an absolute URL (http:// or https://)

     5508 |
    > 5509 |   const testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(<HomePageModel {...fake_props} />);
           |                                     ^
      5510 |   const testInstance = testRenderer.root;
      5511 |

  at defaultLoader (node_modules/next/client/image.tsx:862:6)
      at defaultImageLoader (node_modules/next/client/image.tsx:229:12)
      at node_modules/next/client/image.tsx:199:14
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at generateImgAttrs (node_modules/next/client/image.tsx:197:8)
      at Image (node_modules/next/client/image.tsx:725:20)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6016:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8744:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9966:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13800:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13728:5)
      at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13691:7)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13404:18)
      at node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2537:26
      at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)
      at runWithPriority (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2486:10)
      at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2532:9)
      at flushSyncCallbackQueue (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2519:3)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13004:9)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:16454:3)
      at Object.create (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:17149:3)
      at components/kind-pages/home-page-model.spec.js:5509:37
      at Object.<anonymous> (components/kind-pages/home-page-model.spec.js:12:1)
```

Then I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://blog.jarrodwatts.com/how-to-set-up-nextjs-with-jest-react-testing-library-and-playwright) and noticed I didn't have any `__mocks__` directory, then I created it with a `fileMocks.js` and I got the same result trying with both versions suggested in tutorial:

```
(module.exports = "test-file-stub")
```

and

```
(module.exports = "/test-file-stub")
```

This is what my jest.config.js looked like before tutorial:

```
// jest.config.js
const nextJest = require("next/jest");

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: "./",
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  // if using TypeScript with a baseUrl set to the root directory then you need the below for alias' to work
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "<rootDir>/"],
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/components/$1",
    "^@/utils/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/utils/$1",
    "^@/utils/widgets/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/utils/widgets/$1",
    "^@/contexts/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/contexts/$1",
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
    "^@/public/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/public/$1",
    "^@/public/img/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/public/img/$1",
    "/img/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/public/img/$1",
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setupTests.js"],
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

After reading the tutorial, I added these lines in moduleNameMapper:

```
"^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|avif|svg)$":
  "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
```

and also:

```
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/", "<rootDir>/.next/"],
```

Then, this is the error I get now:

```
   Configuration error:


Could not locate module public/img/logo.png mapped as:
/app/__mocks__/fileMock.js.

Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|avif|svg)$/": "/app/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
  },
  "resolver": undefined
}

  1 | import Image from "next/image";
  2 | import style from "./IndexHeader.module.scss";
> 3 | import LogoImg from "public/img/logo.png";
    |                                                             ^
  4 |
  5 | export default function IndexHeader() {
  6 |   return (

  at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:579:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (components/kind-pages/widgets/index-header.js:3:61)
```

I really can't get what I'm doing wrong. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: When using `next/jest` you don't need to mock images imports, it does it for you automatically.